# How to implement a basic binary search algorithm in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, search, binary

I'm trying to implement a binary search algorithm in Python for a sorted list. I've written the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Can someone help me identify the issue and suggest corrections?
here is my code.....

Comment: Where is your code, bro??

Comment: Anyway, just hit `Binary search in python` in google and a lot of results will show up for you.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Your binary search implementation looks almost correct. However, there's a small issue in the **else** branch of the while loop. When **guess > target**, you should update high to **mid - 1** instead of **low = mid + 1**. Here's the corrected code:

```
def binary_search(arr, target):
low, high = 0, len(arr) - 1

while low <= high:
    mid = (low + high) // 2
    guess = arr[mid]

    if guess == target:
        return mid
    elif guess < target:
        low = mid + 1
    else:
        high = mid - 1

return -1
```

This should fix the issue, and now the binary search should work correctly.